# How to stop reservations before today

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a reservation system for a games library of some sort.
Users should not be allowed to reserve the game for a day before today.

I tried to do this by changing the date chosen by the user for the start of the reservation to a timestamp. Then I would set the date for today, change it to a timestamp and check if the date chosen by the user is less than todays timestamp.

Here is the code:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($ReservationStart);

$todaystamp = (strtotime('yesterday midnight'));

if ($timestamp < $todaystamp) {
    die("The date you've chosen is before today, please choose a valid date");
}
```

I thought this would work but it this code only stops reservations for 2 days past and behind rather than yesterday and behind.

Any ideas on how to get it to work for yesterday?

Comment: What happens if you just do `midnight` or `yesterday`?

Comment: It seems midnight works, thank you!

Comment: No worries, I'll put it into an answer for you :)

Comment: I did not think that midnight would work as I thought it would set the date as midnight today rather than yesterday.

Comment: Yeah, if you want today's midnight you can use `$timestamp = strtotime('today midnight');`

Comment: Thanks. I see how it works now :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is to use `midnight` rather than `yesterday midnight`.

```
$timestamp = strtotime('midnight');
```

It seems that the `strtotime` works backwards, so `yesterday midnight` would be yesterday at `00:00`, so it allows all 24 hours of the next day (yesterday) to be allowed to book in.

`midnight` would go to the current day's midnight (starting at that current date's `00:00`.

If you were worried about getting today's midnight, that would be:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('today midnight');
```

So it's quite easy to understand once you learn that.